# setMyLocation Button will not pop up when application loads

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to display the basic setMyLocation Button when my application loads the map but every time I do so the application crashes and says java.lang.SecurityException: my location requires permission ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3288) I have the necessary permissions included in the manifest

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public GoogleMap map;
    Location location;
    //double lat, longit;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }




    }


  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.cnit425.patrickwalker.assignment2">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission          
android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <uses-permission  android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

        <!-- GoogleMap API v2 Permission -->
        <uses-permission android:name="org.smart_laboratory.laptop.locationmaptest.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"   />
        <!-- GoogleMap API v2 Location related Permission -->
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <!-- GPS & Storage Permission -->
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        <!-- OpenGL Use Setting -->
        <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyCMmSB3RP5MOu7WqZgBBh5jpz-LXy6gQDo"/>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Have you check the [Runtime permission](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) yet? In the devices with android OS more than 5.0, it'll require the runtime permission instead of  in the manifest.

Comment: isn't that what the if statement is doing?